# VS 2017 Build error: error MSB4019: The imported project ... was not found

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am building via VSTS a .Net project and I am getting an error;

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I had a look to see if the file exists on my devlopment machine and I got as far as

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\

There were a number of directories at this point but none called 2.0.0;
[image]

So what do I need to fix?

Comment: What's the agent did you used, hosted agent or the private agent located on  your development machine? And what's your project type? Could you show the full logs and set `system.debug` as `true`?

Comment: The log files are here; https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhERQL5GdvI4rzr6mCQw_FaSyCiG. I am using a hosted agent. I am not sure what you mean about  system.debug as true however. In VS the build is set to debug if that is what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If there both have .net projects and .net core project, you should specify the .net core project for .NET Core publish task.
If you use wildcard (such as **/*.csproj)  to publish not only .net core project, when the task try to publish the project which is a .net project, it will show the error message.

So you should specify the .net core project in .NET Core task as below example:
[image]

Comment: My application contains a web API which is a Core project. The other projects are .Net projects and they are published in seperate tasks, see https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhERQL5GdvI4rzuv3A4if8RZDT7e. The project that fell over was not published in the Core Task.

Comment: So which `.csproj` is .net core project? And can you show the screen shot for the .NET Core task settings?

Comment: I found the Core project had an unintended dependency on the non-core project that caused the fault. I like to think removing that will fix the problem but for now I am having a different problem, I keep getting a login screen when I try to push the latest commit. This should not happen and when I enter my credentials it fails anyway. I am not getting a response to this from MSFT: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/127172/vsts-build-fails-error-cannot-spawn-askpass-no-suc.html. Still this is veering off the original problem.

Comment: Ok, so you need to solve the git push issue before verifying the current issue. What if you push the changes by command line directly? And there has a similar issue for git push by VS as you met https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31370/git-error-when-running-vs-under-account-from-diffe.html.

Comment: My boss got impatient and so we switched to TFVC. Now got new problems.